# php - How to convert 2d array into csv file with adding header

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array

How can i convert my 2d array into csv file with adding header so user can upload the file directly.

Here is my array

```
Array (   
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25/2/2013
            [1] => 8.45 a.m
            [2] => 9.98
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 6.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25/2/2013
            [1] => 8.46 a.m
            [2] => 9.02
            [3] => 1.75
            [4] => 1.75
        )
 )
```

and i want my output as

Date         Time       Value1    Value2    Value3  (all header)

25/2/2013   8.45 a.m     9.98      1.23      6.1

25/2/2013   8.46 a.m     9.02      1.75      1.75

Comment: 1st homework: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
2nd homework: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php
3rd homework: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: 4th homework: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Nice, I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   $header = array("Date","Time","Value1","Value2","Value3");

   $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
   fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");
   foreach($array as $row){
        fputcsv($fp, $row, "\t");
   }
   fclose($fp);
```

If you want to trigger a download for the client add the following lines at the top.

```
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");
  header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=mycoolfile.csv');
```

Comment: do you mind explaining this a bit? Whats `\t` ? What in here handles that the array is multidimensional? How is the array written into the csv? With brackets? Comma? Will it work with more than 2D?

Comment: @sumit look up fputcsv and all will be reveiled

Comment: @sumit also \t is the escape sequence for the tab character. The output is not going to a file at this point but to php://output which is the file descriptor for the output buffer. any writable filename in the fopen call can be used instead.

Comment: if the PHP documentation would be any useful, nobody would search here for the answers ;) I'm using fputcsv already.